# What is Max Pooling?

Tags: neural-networks, artificial-intelligence

What is Max Pooling and why would I use it?

There are a lot of questions about Max Pooling on Stack Exchange, but none of them explain what it is, why we want to use it, the problem it solves, or competing solutions.

I'm looking to build a better conceptual understanding from a beginners perspective.

Comment: You may find this [post from Machine Learning Mastery](https://machinelearningmastery.com/pooling-layers-for-convolutional-neural-networks/) helpful.

Comment: Max pooling takes the largest value out of a patch. You can think of it as a summary statistic that makes your subsequent steps less susceptible to small input perturbations and downsamples the feature space. One could also consider other summary measures like average pooling and compare them e.g. through cross-validation. For certain application domains, the use of specific pooling layers may be well established empirically or theoretically.